# How to run softmodem for OpenAirInterface (OAI) 5G SA on bladeRF A4

Tags: command-line

**I have a problem using bladeRF A4 to make OAI 5G SA**

I use Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) Desktop, on 5.19.0-46-generic. I try OAI on the develop branch and run on bladeRF A4. I follow this [link](https://gitlab.eurecom.fr/oai/openairinterface5g/-/tree/master/targets/ARCH/BLADERF), it suggest to not use command `./build_oai -I -w BLADERF`, but install bladeRF from source.

I finish download bladeRF library and can correctly use interaction mode via command `bladeRF-cli -i`. I use the command to set necessary parameters for bladeRF. The result of setting are shown below.

```
$ sudo bladeRF-cli -i
bladeRF> print frequency

  RX1 Frequency: 2400000000 Hz (Range: [70000000, 6000000000])
  RX2 Frequency: 2400000000 Hz (Range: [70000000, 6000000000])
  TX1 Frequency: 2400000000 Hz (Range: [47000000, 6000000000])
  TX2 Frequency: 2400000000 Hz (Range: [47000000, 6000000000])

bladeRF> print gain

  Gain RX1 overall:   60 dB (Range: [-15, 60])
              full:   71 dB (Range: [-4, 71])
  Gain RX2 overall:   60 dB (Range: [-15, 60])
              full:   71 dB (Range: [-4, 71])
  Gain TX1 overall:   56 dB (Range: [-23.75, 66])
               dsa:  -90 dB (Range: [-89.75, 0])
  Gain TX2 overall:   56 dB (Range: [-23.75, 66])
               dsa:  -90 dB (Range: [-89.75, 0])

bladeRF> print bandwidth

  RX1 Bandwidth:  18000000 Hz (Range: [200000, 56000000])
  RX2 Bandwidth:  18000000 Hz (Range: [200000, 56000000])
  TX1 Bandwidth:  18000000 Hz (Range: [200000, 56000000])
  TX2 Bandwidth:  18000000 Hz (Range: [200000, 56000000])

bladeRF> print samplerate

  RX1 sample rate: 30720000 0/1 (Range: [520834, 122880000])
  RX2 sample rate: 30720000 0/1 (Range: [520834, 122880000])
  TX1 sample rate: 30720000 0/1 (Range: [520834, 122880000])
  TX2 sample rate: 30720000 0/1 (Range: [520834, 122880000])
```

All I have mentioned are part of step 1 - 3 of the [link](https://gitlab.eurecom.fr/oai/openairinterface5g/-/tree/master/targets/ARCH/BLADERF). And now I have problem in step 4, which said I can run softmodem now. The instruction of this step is included here.

```
4. Tune the RX gain using the enb tracer.

    Run the softmodem and the 'enb' tracer. For instructions, see:

        https://gitlab.eurecom.fr/oai/openairinterface5g/wikis/T/basic

    In the enb window, check the 'input signal'. You should see some blue
    signal as seen at:

        https://gitlab.eurecom.fr/oai/openairinterface5g/wikis/T/enb
```

**Please help me how can I run softmodem?**
How to correctly build OAI for bladeRF to run 5G SA?

note: I try this [link](https://gitlab.eurecom.fr/oai/openairinterface5g/-/blob/develop/doc/RUNMODEM.md#sa-setup-with-oai-nr-ue) as it have softmodem command here.

```
sudo ./nr-softmodem -O ../../../targets/PROJECTS/GENERIC-NR-5GC/CONF/gnb.sa.band78.fr1.106PRB.usrpb210.conf --gNBs.[0].min_rxtxtime 6 --rfsim --sa
```

but when i trace the command to see where they open the project, inside the folder `targets/PROJECTS/GENERIC-NR-5GC/CONF` there is nothing related to bladeRF, only USRP which is an SDR from Ettus

```
~/ubuntu_work2/openairinterface5g/targets/PROJECTS/GENERIC-NR-5GC/CONF$ ls
cu_gnb.conf
du_gnb.conf
gnb0.sa.band261.fr2.64PRB.prs.usrpx310.conf
gnb0.sa.band78.fr1.106PRB.prs.usrpx310.conf
gnb1.sa.band261.fr2.64PRB.prs.usrpx310.conf
gnb1.sa.band78.fr1.106PRB.prs.usrpx310.conf
gnb.band78.sa.fr1.106PRB.2x2.usrpn310.conf
gnb.band78.sa.fr1.162PRB.2x2.usrpn310.conf
gnb.band78.tm1.106PRB.usrpn300.gtp-itti.conf
gNB_SA_40_2x2.conf
gnb.sa.band41.fr1.106PRB.usrpb210.conf
gnb.sa.band41.fr1.52PRB.usrpb210.conf
gnb.sa.band66.fr1.106PRB.usrpn300.conf
gnb.sa.band66.fr1.106PRB.usrpx300.conf
gnb.sa.band66.fr1.24PRB.usrpx300.conf
gnb.sa.band66.fr1.25PRB.usrpx300.conf
gnb.sa.band77.fr1.273PRB.2x2.usrpn300.conf
gnb.sa.band77.fr1.273PRB.usrpx300.conf
gnb.sa.band78.fr1.106PRB.2x2.usrpn300.conf
gnb.sa.band78.fr1.106PRB.usrpb210.4layer.conf
gnb.sa.band78.fr1.106PRB.usrpb210.conf
gnb.sa.band78.fr1.106PRB.usrpb210.sabox.conf
gnb.sa.band78.fr1.162PRB.2x2.usrpn300.conf
gnb.sa.band78.fr1.217PRB.2x2.usrpn300.conf
gnb.sa.band78.fr1.24PRB.usrpb210.conf
pnf.sa.band78.rfsim.conf
uecap_ports1.xml
uecap_ports2.xml
ue.conf
ue.nr.prs.fr1.106prb.conf
ue.nr.prs.fr2.64prb.conf
vnf.sa.band78.106prb.rfsim.conf
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me what I'm missing and sorry for not informing, I use Ubuntu 22.04 on a generic kernel. I try OAI on the develop branch and run on bladeRF A4. Should I provide more detail please let me know. I am so new to this. Thank you for your comment to tell me what I am missing.

Comment: Thank you, I check again, I use Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) Desktop, on 5.19.0-46-generic.

Comment: did you find a solution and get it work? I have the bladeRF A9 device and get the error `[LOADER] library liboai_device.so successfully loaded
Error: unknown sampling rate 61440000.000000`. When I try a config with 51PRB, the gNB runs, but COTS UE doesn't recognize the SA network :-(